# How to rewrite bool TrySomething(List<T> items, out List<T> itemsThatFailed)

Tags: c#, design-patterns, coding-style, out

I have this function:

```
bool TrySomething(IEnumerable<T> items, out List<T> listOfProblemItems)
{
    //...

    return listOfProblemItems != null && listOfProblemItems.Count > 0;
}
```

Right now is works opposite of what you would expect from the "TrySomething" pattern (e.g. `TryParse`):

It returns `true` if something went wrong (to indicate that the `out` parameter has been filled with info). So that I can call it like this:

```
if(TrySomething(items, out problemItems))
{
   //handle problems
   //"but.. it returned 'true'! Why are there problems? I'm confused."
}
```

It's not intuitive to return `true` if there were problems, but if I change it to `false`, then the `out` parameter would be filled with info on `false` and thus breaking the "TrySomething" pattern.

```
if(TrySomething(items, out problemItems) == false)
{
   //handle problems
   //"the 'out' parameter is used? but it returned false! I'm confused."
}
```

It is **not an alternative for me to throw exceptions** as this is a high performance piece, and I need a clearly defined list of which items failed anyway.

I could make it *return* the problem list and name it `TrySomethingAndReturnAnyProblems`, but that name is ugly and the calling code would have to check the returned list for null and the count, which I'd rather have done in the function because it always has to be done anyway.

```
List<T> problems = TrySomethingAndReturnAnyProblems(items);
if(problems != null && problems.Count > 0)
{
    //ugly and introduces duplicate code every time the function is used.
}
```

How can I make this into a readable, self-documenting function definition while retaining the conciseness of the "TrySomething" pattern?

Comment: what about `return listOfProblemItems == null || listOfProblemItems.Count == 0;`? BTW I would remove `bool` return value and I'd return list directly. Caller can simply check for an empty list...

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't use the `TryX` pattern. `TryX` methods use `out` parameters for results, not for reporting problems. You're breaking the pattern right there and then.

Comment: First of all, a custom exception type could of course contain a list of problems. Secondly, exceptions aren't slow when they aren't thrown. Put differently: when your program does not work, does it really have to not work _quickly_? Last but not least, exceptions might not be as slow as you seem to think. You're building a list of problems, and looping over that list afterwards. The exception cost in that process will most likely be negligeable.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten:he is writing a method that expects to fail often, otherwise the method itself would be redundant.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten You might be right about the performance cost in comparison to the rest of the function. But it's not an *exceptional* case - I get problem items back very regularly. So to use exceptions still "smells".

Comment: @dcastro Yes but then what should I use that is still as clear and self-documenting as that pattern?

Comment: How about a `int TrySomething(IEnumerable<T> items, Action<T> problemCallback)` ?

Comment: Read `API Design Myth: Exceptions are for "Exceptional Errors"` at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kcwalina/archive/2008/07/17/exceptionalerror.aspx

Comment: @MarcGravell Yeah that seems quite self-documenting... I may be able to use it, although I'd probably change it to `TrySomething(IEnumerable<T> items, Action<IEnumerable<T>> problemCallback)` to be able to call `TrySomething` again with corrected items all at once (to leverage performance benefits of calling the function with many items).

Comment: @DavidS no, for that the iterator block (one of the answers) would be better

Comment: @MarcGravell I don't see the reason for preferring that, can you elaborate? I'm thinking it would be practical to have all items handled at once.

Comment: @DavidS that depends on the numbers involved, and whether that represents an overhead. Are there 10 items? or 100000?

Comment: @MarcGravell Usually several thousand to a few hundred thousand. In this particular case I'm sending the items to azure table storage asynchronously (with some limit to the amount of items 'in transit' depending on the amount of responses), which is an absolutely massive speed-up rather than trying one by one.

Comment: @DavidS. the problem is, constantly creating things like lists or arrays of a few hundred thousand is a good way to fragment your large object heap...

Answer (score 2):

How about writing an extension method to simply filter out the problematic items? That way, you could only get back the items which are OK, e.g.:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ExceptProblematic(this IEnumerable<T> items)
{
  foreach (var item in items)
  {
    if (!IsProblematic(item))
      yield return item;
  }
}
```

This way you could use it like:

```
var validItems = items.ExceptProblematic();
```

Alternatively, you could write a query to ONLY return the problem items, then make another query to filter them out, e.g.:

```
var problemItems = items.Where(item => IsProblematic(item));
var validItems = items.Except(problemItems);
```

Then handle problem items accordingly:

```
if (problemItems.Any()) 
{
   // handle problem items
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what `IsProblematic(item)` would do except for trying to run the operation and see. In which case I could just have created a `bool TrySomething(T item)`, which I can't because it's a high performant function that only is useful when a large number of items are passed.

Answer (score 2):

What about creating a `Result<T>` class with a `bool Success` and `T Data` properties?

```
class Result<T>
{
     public bool Success {get; set;}
     public T Data {get; set;}
}
```

Then make `TrySomething` return `Result<List<T>>`

```
Result<List<T>> result = TrySomething(enumerable);
if (!result.Success)
{
    List<T> problematicItems = result.Data;
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather create a special class for the outcome (see Ahmed KRAIEM's answer) 
but I'd do it in some different (elaborated) manner:

```
  public sealed class SomeResultWithDescription<TItem>: IReadOnlyList<TItem> {
    private List<TItem> m_Problems;
    private Boolean m_Success = true; // <- the field may be redundant 

    // may be redundant: if there's no situation when the result is falure
    // even if there're no problems enlisted
    internal SomeResultWithDescription(List<TItem> problems, Boolean success)
      : this(problems) {

      m_Success = success;
    }

    internal SomeResultWithDescription(List<TItem> problems)
      : base() {

      if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, problems))
        m_Problems = new List<TItem>();
      else
        m_Problems = problems;
    }

    public IReadOnlyList<TItem> Problems {
      get {
        return m_Problems;
      }
    }

    public Boolean Success {
      get {
        if (!m_Success)
          return false;
        else if (m_Problems.Count > 0)
          return false;

        return true;
      }
    }

    public Boolean ToBoolean() {
      return Success;
    }

    public static implicit operator Boolean(SomeResultWithDescription<TItem> value) {
      if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, value))
        return false;

      return value.ToBoolean();
    }

    public TItem this[int index] {
      get {
        return m_Problems[index];
      }
    }

    public int Count {
      get {
        return m_Problems.Count;
      }
    }

    public IEnumerator<TItem> GetEnumerator() {
      return m_Problems.GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
      return m_Problems.GetEnumerator();
    }
  }

  ...

  // Your method will be
  SomeResultWithDescription<T> TrySomething(IEnumerable<T> items)
  {
    //...

    return new SomeResultWithDescription<T>(listOfProblemItems);
  }

  // So you can do
  // 1. Just do if no problems detected
  if (TrySomething(items)) { 
    ...
  }

  // 2. Do if no problems, analyze if there're problems
  var result = TrySomething(items);

  if (result) { 
    ... // no problems
  }
  else { // <- some problems to analyze
    foreach (var problem in result) {
      ...
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about breaking the `TryX` pattern, why don't you make one up:

```
public bool AntiTrySomething(IEnumerable<T> input, out IEnumerable<T> fails)
{
    // implement me - return true if fail
}
```

As long as you're consistent throughout your codebase I think something like this is clear and separates you from the "standard" enough not to conflict with it whilst keeping familiarity.